# Writing a syscall to count context switches of a process

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, context-switch

I have to do a system call to count the voluntary & involuntary context switches of a process. I already know the steps to add a new system call to a linux kernel but i have no clue of where i should start for the context-switch function. Any idea?

Comment: Look at the sched() function. http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your syscall should only report statistics, you can use context switch counting code that is already in the kernel.

[wait3 syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait3) or [getrusage syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) already reports context switch count in `struct rusage` fields:

```
struct rusage {
 ...
    long   ru_nvcsw;         /* voluntary context switches */
    long   ru_nivcsw;        /* involuntary context switches */
};
```

You can try it by running:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v /bin/ls -R
....
    Voluntary context switches: 1669
    Involuntary context switches: 207
```

where "`/bin/ls -R`" is any program.

By searching an "struct rusage" in kernel sources, you can find [this `accumulate_thread_rusage`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/kernel/sys.c#L1477) in kernel/sys.c, which updates rusage struct. It reads from `struct task_struct *t`; the fields `t->nvcsw;` and `t->nivcsw;`:

```
1477  static void accumulate_thread_rusage(struct task_struct *t, struct rusage *r)
1478  {
1479        r->ru_nvcsw += t->nvcsw;    // <<=== here
1480        r->ru_nivcsw += t->nivcsw;
1481        r->ru_minflt += t->min_flt;
1482        r->ru_majflt += t->maj_flt;
```

Then you should search `nvcsw` and `nivcsw` in kernel folder to find how they are updated by kernel.

[asmlinkage void __sched schedule(void)](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/kernel/sched.c#L4128):

```
4124     if (likely(prev != next)) {         // <= if we are switching between different tasks
4125            sched_info_switch(prev, next);
4126            perf_event_task_sched_out(prev, next);
4127
4128            rq->nr_switches++;          
4129            rq->curr = next;
4130            ++*switch_count;     // <= increment nvcsw or nivcsw via pointer
4131
4132            context_switch(rq, prev, next); /* unlocks the rq */
```

Pointer `switch_count` is from [line 4091](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/kernel/sched.c#L4091) or [line 4111](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/kernel/sched.c#L4111) of the same file.

PS: Link from perreal is great:  http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html (search `context_swtch`)

Answer (score 5):

This already exists: the virtual file `/proc/NNNN/status` (where NNNN is the decimal process ID of the process you want to know about) contains, among other things, counts of both voluntary and involuntary context switches.  Unlike `getrusage` this allows you to learn the context switch counts for *any* process, not just children.  See the [`proc(5)` manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A process will make a context switch in case of blocking, time quantum expiring or for interrupts etc. Eventually schedule() function is called. Since you want to count it for each process separately you have to keep a new variable for each process for counting the no of context switches. And you can update this variable each time in schedule fun for current process. Using your system call you can read this value. Here is a snippet of the schedule function of pintos,

```
static void
schedule (void) 
{
  struct thread *cur = running_thread ();
  struct thread *next = next_thread_to_run ();
  struct thread *prev = NULL;

  ASSERT (intr_get_level () == INTR_OFF);
  ASSERT (cur->status != THREAD_RUNNING);
  ASSERT (is_thread (next));<br/>

  if (cur != next)
    prev = switch_threads (cur, next);  <== here you can update count of "cur"   
  thread_schedule_tail (prev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Total number of context switches**

`cat /proc/PID/sched|grep nr_switches`

**Voluntary context switches**

`cat /proc/PID/sched | grep nr_voluntary_switches`

**Involuntary context switches**

`cat /proc/PID/sched|grep nr_involuntary_switches`

where PID is process ID of the process you wish to monitor.

However if you want to get these statistics by patching (creating a hook) linux source, the code related to scheduling is present in

kernel/sched/

folder of the source tree.
In particular

kernel/sched/core.c contains the schedule() function, which is the code of linux scheduler.
The code of CFS (completely fair scheduler), which is one of the several schedulers present in Linux, and is most commonly used is present in

/kernel/sched/fair.c

scheduler() is executed when ever TIF_NEED_RESCHED flag is set, so find out from which all places this flag is being set (use cscope on linux source) which will give you an insight intsight into the types of context switches occurring for a process.